# Reference melt variable column to calculate another column in datafrane

Tags: python, pandas, melt

Using python/pandas I have used the melt() function to transform my data

```
Person  Score1  Score2  V1  V2
A   1   4   6   8
B   2   5   3   6
C   3   6   4   7
```

into the form

```
 Person variable  value  V1  V2
0      A   Score1      1   6  8
1      B   Score1      2   3  6
2      C   Score1      3   4  7
3      A   Score2      4   6  8
4      B   Score2      5   3  6
5      C   Score2      6   4  7
```

I now want to add another column V where

> V = V1 if variable = Score1, else = V2 if variable = Score2

resulting in:

```
  Person variable  value  V
0      A   Score1      1  6
1      B   Score1      2  3
2      C   Score1      3  4
3      A   Score2      4  8
4      B   Score2      5  6
5      C   Score2      6  7
```

I tried using var_name to name the variable attribute but it doesnt seem to really define it so im struggling to use it to calculate the values for the V column, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np

df['v'] = np.where(df['variable']== 'Score1', df['V1'], df['V2'])

# if you want to drop the columns
# df.drop(['V1','V2], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['Score','V'], i=['index'], j='variable')
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .reset_index()
       .assign(variable= lambda x: 'Score' + x['variable'].astype(str))
       )
print (df)
  variable Person  Score  V
0   Score1      A      1  6
1   Score1      B      2  3
2   Score1      C      3  4
3   Score2      A      4  8
4   Score2      B      5  6
5   Score2      C      6  7
```

Comment: why not `np.where` ?

Comment: @pyd - here is better use `wide_to_long` instead `melt`, so `np.where` is not necessary.